# Page hit count or Google Analytics?

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics, counter

I'm developing a website that is sensitive to page visits. For instance it has sections that will show the users which parts of the website (which items) have been visited the most. To implement this features, two strategies come to my mind:

1. Create a page hit counter, sort the pages by the number of visits and pick the highest ones.
2. Create a Google Analytics account and use its info.

If the first strategy has been chosen, I would need a very fast and accurate hit counter with the ability to distinguish the unique IPs (or users). I believe that using MySQL wouldn't be a good choice, since a lot of page visits, means a lot of DB locks and performance problems. I think a fast logging class would be a good one.

The second option seems very interesting when all the problems of the first one emerge but I don't know if there is a way (like an API) for Google Analytics to make me able to access the information I want. And if there is, is it fast enough?

Which approach (or even an alternative approach) you suggest I should take? Which one is faster? The performance is my top priority. Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
Thank you. It's interesting to see different answers. These answers reminded me an important factor. My website updates the "most visited" items, every 8 minutes so I don't need the data in real time but I need it to be accurate enoughe every 8 minutes or so. What I had in mind was this:

1. Log every page visit to a simple text log file
2. Send a cookie to the user to separate unique users
3. Every 8 minutes, load the log file, collect the info and update the MySQL tables.

That said, I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel. If a 3rd party service can meet my requirements, I would be happy to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you are planning to use the page hit data to determine what data to display on your site, I'd suggest logging the page hit info yourself. You don't want to be reliant upon some 3rd party service that you'd have to interrogate in order to create your page. This is especially true if you are loading that data real time as you'd have to interrogate that service for every incoming request to your site.

I'd be inclined to save the data yourself in a database. If you're really concerned about the performance of the inserts, then you could investigate intercepting requests (I'm not sure how you go about this in PHP, but I'm assuming it's possible.) and then passing the request data of to a separate thread to store the request info. By having a separate thread handle the logging, then you won't interrupt your response to the end user.

Also, given you are planning using the data collected to "... show the users which parts of the website (which items) have been visited the most", then you'll need to think about accessing this data to build your dynamic page. Maybe it'd be good to store a consolidated count for each resource. For example, rather than having 30000 rows showing that index.php was requested, maybe have one row showing index.php was requested 30000 times. This would certainly be quicker to reference than having to perform queries on what could become quite a large table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please read the update in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure that your edit would make me adjust my response too much. If anything, I would simply restate that in my mind, it'd be better to  create a consolidated list of resources and hits as I'd outlined in my last paragraph. Even if you wanted to, you could simply have a map of resources and associated hit counts, and then just update Mysql once every x minutes if you are worried about database access being a bottleneck. I think this would be faster than parsing a log file. Best of luck with what ever approach you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has a latency to it and it samples some of the data returned to the API so that's out.

You could try the [API from Clicky](http://getclicky.com/help/apps-plugins#/help/api). Bear in mind that:

> Free accounts are limited to the last 30 days of history, and 100 results per request.

There are many examples of hit counters out there, but it sounds like you didn't find one that met your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please read the update in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't need real-time data.  If that's the case, I'd probably just read the data out of the web server log files.

Your web server can distinguish IP addresses. There's no fully reliable way to distinguish users. I live in a university town; half the dormitory students have the same university IP address. I think Google Analytics relies on cookies to identify users, but shared computers makes that somewhat less than 100% reliable. (But that might not be a big deal.)

"Visited the most" is also a little fuzzy. The easy way out is to count every hit on a particular page as a visit. But a "visit" of 300 milliseconds is of questionable worth.  (Probably realized they clicked the wrong link, and hit the "back" button before the page rendered.)

Unless there are requirements I don't know about, I'd probably start by using awk to extract timestamp, ip address, and page name into a CSV file, then load the CSV file into a database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please read the update in my question.